# php code in jquery script in php file

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form `filename.php` and within this I have called a jquery function and I would like to include the following php code within that jquery function

```
<?php
  //require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "your_private_key";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
  }
  ?>
```

How can I do that?

**Edit**

I want to define a variable when the form is submitted:

```
<?php
  //require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "your_private_key";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    $cverify = false;
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
    $cverify = true;
  }
  ?>
```

And now in js code if I have the following code and if I type correct verification code then also it alerts false

```
var cverify = '<?php echo json_encode($cverify); ?>';
        alert(cverify);
```

So how can I get checked verification when submit button is clicked?

Comment: Your question seems unclear to me... Can you show what you have right now.. The jQuery function inside the PHP file.

Comment: Are you trying to validate recaptcha within javascript/jQuery using php as the backend? shouldn't you be using ajax?

Comment: yes you are right..... but I don't know how to use here...

Comment: Javascript is clientside and php is server side.

Answer (score 0):

On submit send an ajax request to filename.php with the entered captcha code from the formular as paramterer and in the filename.php check your captcha. If the check is correct return "true" as string else "false".

In your ajax request on complete compare the return value of filename.php against "true". If successful continue submiting the form to the server.

**Please make sure that you also check your form serverside because someone could have javasctipt disabled and can therefore submit unchecked data. So you need to check the captcha on serverside again.**

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "filename.php",
}).done(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    if (jqXHR.response != "correct") {
        alert('wrong captcha');
    } else {
        alert('correct');
    }
});
```

filename.php:

```
<?php
//require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "your_private_key";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    echo 'wrong';
} else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
    echo 'correct';
}

/* EOF */
```

I don't know whats inside the function recaptcha_check_answer() but you need sessions to check the captcha. And I don't see that you start a session in your filename.php.